# SessionTimeout: web.xml vs session.maxInactiveInterval()

Tags: java, session, servlets, weblogic, session-timeout

I'm trying to timeout an *HttpSession* in Java. My container is WebLogic.

Currently, we have our session timeout set in the *web.xml* file, like this

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Now, I'm being told that this will terminate the session (or is it all sessions?) in the 15th minute of use, regardless their activity.

I'm wondering if this approach is the correct one, or should I programatically set the time limit of inactivity by

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15 * 60); //15 minutes
```

I don't want to drop all sessions at 15 minutes, only those that have been inactive for 15 minutes.

Are these methods equivalent? Should I favour the *web.xml* config?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

> Now, i'm being told that this will terminate the session (or is it all sessions?) in the 15th minute of use, *regardless their activity*.

This is **wrong**. It will just kill the session when the associated client (webbrowser) has not accessed the website for more than 15 minutes. The activity certainly counts, exactly as you initially expected, seeing your attempt to solve this.

The [`HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) doesn't change much here by the way. It does exactly the same as `<session-timeout>` in `web.xml`, with the only difference that you can change/set it programmatically during runtime. The change by the way only affects the current session instance, not globally (else it would have been a `static` method).

---

To play around and experience this *yourself*, try to set `<session-timeout>` to 1 minute and create a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) like follows:

```
@WebListener
public class HttpSessionChecker implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s created at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s destroyed at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }

}
```

*(if you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet and thus can't use `@WebListener`, then register in `web.xml` as follows)*:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.HttpSessionChecker</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note that the servletcontainer won't immediately destroy sessions after *exactly* the timeout value. It's a background job which runs at certain intervals (e.g. 5~15 minutes depending on load and the servletcontainer make/type). So don't be surprised when you don't see `destroyed` line in the console immediately after exactly one minute of inactivity. However, when you fire a HTTP request on a timed-out-but-not-destroyed-yet session, it will be destroyed immediately.

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909)

Comment: Furthermore, to clarify.  This configuration applies to all sessions.

Comment: One other thing to note - setting the value to 0 or less in the web.xml means sessions will never timeout (not as long as the servlet container is alive anyway). However, setting it to 0 programatically causes the session to timeout immediately (setting it to a negative number means the session wil never timeout, same as in web.xml).

Comment: Also, note that maxInactiveInterval defaults to 60 seconds http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: @BalusC , "when you fire a HTTP request on a timed-out-but-not-destroyed-yet session, it will be destroyed immediately", do you know if the session is destroyed 1. before any controller code is executed or 2. simultaneously/asynchronously with the controller logic? I am guessing 1. but am not sure.

Answer (score 13):

> Now, i'm being told that this will terminate the session (or is it all sessions?) in the 15th minute of use, regardless their activity.

No, that's not true. The `session-timeout` configures a per session timeout in case of inactivity.

> Are these methods equivalent? Should I favour the web.xml config?

The setting in the web.xml is global, it applies to all sessions of a given context. Programatically, you can change this for a particular session.