# session expire and back button of browser in jsp and sevlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout)

I have to create a login and logout page with sessions. Now I have to invalidate the session after a certain interval of time and after clicking logout button. After session expiry time and logout action no one should be access previous pages by clicking back button of browser without again logging.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will want to try solving the problem on your own first. Asking for full working code isn't what this site is for. Try re-phrasing your question and giving some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("loggedVendor");

        if (userName == null)
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
            throws ServletException {
        // We can initialize a filter using the init-params here
        // (which we defined in the deployment descriptor - web.xml)
    }

<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @Andrey Sir i did as you directed but page is not redirecting to login page

Answer (score 1):

Set the session timeout in the `web.xml` file:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

Put in the session user's name when an user's logged:

```
session.setAttribute(userName, "userName");
```

And kill it when an user's logged out:

```
session.removeAttribute("userName");
```

Create a filter to validate an user, like this:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                                          throws   IOException, ServletException { 

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request; 

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(); 

        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("userName"); 

        if (userName == null) { 
           rejectRedirect();  
        } 

        chain.doFilter(request, response);  
    }

    private void rejectRedirect() {
        response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp"); // or warning page
    }
}
```

And map this filter in the `web.xml`:

```
<filter> 
   <filter-name>Authorization Filter</filter-name> 
   <filter-class>yourpackage.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>Authorization Filter</filter-name> 
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Sir i went through ur suggestions but I am not getting how to use this in login and logout page .

Comment: Will you plz guide me upto there As i dont have the idea to use this.

Comment: Create submit button `logout` in form: `<form action="logout.jsp"><input type="submit" value="Logout"/></form>`. Delete session attribute on the `logout.jsp` page. This isn't certainly the best approach in terms of app architecture. But such decision will be acceptable for a test application.

Comment: I believe that you're not understanding the concrete question.

Comment: @BalusC Do you suppose my solution will not work?

Comment: No, you are just answering a completely different question which the OP didn't initially ask at all (and are thus completely confusing the OP as to how to implement this "solution"). Check the possible duplicate link comment on the question to see a clearer question and the right answer.

Comment: @Andrey thank you Sir for ur suggestion .sir i dont have idea of how to use filter with my login and logout page with session.plz sir give me example of login and logut page .thank u sir

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik Sir Plz help me out .I know u are directing me to the right way but because of less knowledge i ma not able to complete.

Comment: First read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout/4194251#4194251). And study these simple examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/cont.102/a75172/jsp.html#1016013) and [here](http://www.roseindia.net/quickguide/tomcat/Logout.shtml). They'll help you to understand principle of the mechanism login/logout.

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik Sir ,i did as per ur suggestion but getting infinite loop error because of filters .will u please guide me to resolve this.

Comment: My failure! Rename the page `login.jsp` on `login.html` if it contains only the HTML code. Or another solution is to create a directory `jsp` and put in it all your JSP pages except the `login.jsp`. And in this case change the mapping of the filter in `web.xml`: `<url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>`. Like this the filter'll check all pages except the login-page.

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik thank you Sir .it worked but still my page is not redirecting to index.jsp page after session time of 1 min. i posted my code.plz see .

Comment: This code is incorrect. See my previous comment.

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik Sir i changed web.xml and put all jsp pages inside jsp folder except this not redirecting to login page .

Comment: First, redirect doesn't happen automatically. For this to happen, you must send a request to server for this page. And the second is that a web server executes destroying of session at certain intervals. It happens not immediately. Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118968/sessiontimeout-web-xml-vs-session-maxinactiveinterval/3119074#3119074).

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik Thank you very much sir.but how to use this in my code .do i have to use this code in evry page .Sir ,plz help me other wise it will be a big problem for me