# Default Session time out in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have one login page of JSF application. Once I left login page idle for 30 minutes or more than that, then input login id and password and submit button than getting message:

> The website cannont display the page - an HTTP 500 error.

while i did not configure anywhere timeout in application and I am using web sphere server for deploying the application.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118968/sessiontimeout-web-xml-vs-session-maxinactiveinterval

Answer (score 1):

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

above code in web.xml file solve my problem. Thanks everybody for your help.