# What is the behavior of the session properties in the initOptions.js and worklight.properties file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm looking to understand the behavior of the session properties that are defined in the following files

**initOptions.js**

```
// # Worklight server connection timeout
//timeout: 30000,
```

Does this parameter affect the client mobile app and disconnect the connection to the Worklight Server after the defined interval ?

**worklight.properties**

```
#####################################################################
#   Idle session timeout in minutes
#####################################################################
#serverSessionTimeout=10
```

Does this override the Web Container session timeout property on the JEE server to close or destroy idle sessions after the given time interval ?

Comment: Glen, is this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `initOptions.js`, the `timeout` property relates to the amount of time the app will wait for a connection to the Worklight Server.
2. In `worklight.properties`, the `serverSessionTimeout` property does the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)

   You can also take a look at this question: [SessionTimeout: web.xml vs session.maxInactiveInterval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118968/sessiontimeout-web-xml-vs-session-maxinactiveinterval)

   In short, it does what you wrote.

Comment: Hello Idan, Can you explain how to forcefully stop session on WLClient.logout() ?