# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Does SessionTimeout Overrides App server timeout?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, session-timeout, worklight-server

In IBM Worklight 6.1, does the `serverSessionTimeout` property from the `worklight.properties` overrides the regular timeout configured in the App server ? In my case, I am running on Worklight on top of IBM Liberty, so the session timeout definition is set at `<httpsession invalidationTimeout>`.

In summary, what is the precedence? Worklight Session Timeout or App Server session timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `serverSessionTimeout` property in `server\conf\worklight.properties` (which will later sit in the project's .war file which you deploy to the WAS Liberty profile application server), you will override the default timeout value provided.

See this related question: [What is the behavior of the session properties in the initOptions.js and worklight.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452340/what-is-the-behavior-of-the-session-properties-in-the-initoptions-js-and-worklig)