# Session-Timeout don't work in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, session

Well, i'm trying to configure a Session-Timeout because the users are logged about 15 days without Session expires and i don't wanna this. I have a ManagedBean with @Session scope that stores the user logged in.

I did the following configuration in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>4</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

After this setting, i wait almost 10 minutes without any request in browser but the session keep alive.

What is wrong ? How can i configure a Session-TimeOut ?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't other ajax requests from your client to the server?

Comment: This is the way.. Try to redeploy. this is not make sense

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, i tried close browser,wait 10 minutes and open again (the session keeps alive).

Comment: Are you sure you redeployed the application? Otherwise, there's another problem within your configuration that is not posted here.

Comment: I used Maven to Clean and Install application again, what more can i do ?

Comment: Clean and install application is not the same as redeploying it... Those options only allow you to create the war (or whatever kind of project you're working with). Redeploy means to deploy the artifact in the application server.

Comment: How can i dot it ? Just remove my application and add again in server ? I'm using ECLIPSE IDE

Comment: I already did the "redeploy" but the problem continue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118968/sessiontimeout-web-xml-vs-session-maxinactiveinterval

I

Comment: i tried "listener-class" but didn't work too, don't show any information about session create and destroy